# Error on doctrine:schema:update, table with name already exists

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

in my entity Class i have added some new attributes and i want to update schema of my database. So when i run php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force im getting this error every time

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException]

The table with name 'postgres.day' already exists.
```

and my database won't update. So does anyone know how to solve this problem?

I have read the other question with that problem but it didn't helped me. So can anyone explain me whats going on, or how to solve this? Thanks.

```
<?php

namespace DashboardBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * RadniNalog
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class RadniNalog
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="time_from", type="string", length=255)
     */
     private $time_from;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="time_to", type="string", length=255)
     */
     private $time_to;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="full_date_time", type="string", length=255)
     */
     private $full_date_time;

}
```

Comment: What do you get for `app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql --complete`?

Answer (score 0):

it can cause this error message if you want to use a table name which is already used by one of the installed bundles.

In your case the conflicting table name is: day.

Answer (score -1):

`@ORM\Table` no name provided within your annotation, which is required. See: [Doctrine ORM | 21. Annotations Reference](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#table)

`@ORM\Table(name="radniNalog")`

Either don't add the annotation if you want the default behaviour of Doctrine or add it correctly with the required options.

Comment: It is not true that the `@ORM\Table` requires the `name` property. The default is to use the class name. Same goes for property/column names, by the way. (The Doctrine docs are wrong there.)